# Software to track all kind of activity

Tags: windows, gratis, logs

Currently I use ManicTime. It tracks what software, document I'm currently using.

Is there a software to track all kind of activities? And it should be lot more intelligent.

Examples:

- I'm listening to music. The software will track which music I was listening to + at which time, etc.
- I'm watching movies. It will track at which time I was watching the movie. + where I was in that movie (I mean it will track timing also) etc.
- I'm programming, video editing. It will track which project I was in + what I did etc.

Basically it will track every kind of activity. I like to see in the future that what I did in the past. That's why asking.

Is there any software like this?

Comment: I have a question, why do you want another software recommendation other than ManicTime? Could you tell us what ManicTime features that don't meet your need?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [**RescueTime**](https://www.rescuetime.com/).

**RescueTime** is a time tracking application that runs in background without you doing anything. This application tracks which programs or applications you spend time using. You can adjust your settings which applications are productive and which ones aren't. This application also gives you detailed reports. Example of detailed report is shown below (picture is taken from [here](http://blog.rescuetime.com/category/product-roadmap/)):

[image]

RescumeTime is available on both computer and mobile devices. It's available for Windows. There are two plans that you can choose (free and paid plans). The paid plan supports tracking time eventhough you are away from you computer. Since you don't mention about pricing, you can take a look [this page](https://www.rescuetime.com/plans) for details.

Comment: nvm :3 is there any free software . RescumeTime has lot of limitation in free version.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know if you're looking for free software. You should tell us about it in advance.